# How should I handle data files when testing with NUnit?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, nunit

Say I have a file `data.xml`. I want to open this relative to my application, to start with just next to my exectuable using for example `File.Open(data.xml)`. I added the file as an existing resource to my Visual Studio (2017) project and configured it to be copied to output directory on build. This works.

My issue is that I have a second project in my Solution containing my NUnit tests, referencing the main project. When this builds before I run my tests, this does *not* copy `data.xml` to the test binary directory and the test fails because it can't open the file (obviously).

How should I handle external files when doing unit tests? I would much prefer to not use absolute paths.

Comment: You could include the file in the test project as a [linked file](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jjameson/2009/04/02/linked-files-in-visual-studio-solutions/)?

Comment: You can make the file as an embedded resource.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that the data file is used by the app, not just by the tests.
When VS copies the app into your test output directory, it does not copy anything else, as you have seen.

There are several ways to go here...

1. Add a post-build step to your test project to copy the file from the app output directory to the test output directory. This will work but is messy to maintain. I don't recommend it.
2. Embed the resource in your app and change it to use the resource rather than an external file. Drawback is that it may require multiple changes in the app, depending on how you access the data. It won't work at all if the intent is that changing the file will immediately change the app's behavior without re-compiling it.
3. Change one or both apps to use a common output directory. That way, whenever the data changes it is copied and becomes available to all your tests. That's the way I generally like to handle the situation.